# Flutter integration test, how to ensure user is signed out? (flushed state)

Tags: flutter, testing, integration-testing, flutter-test, end-to-end

I'm writing my first Flutter integrations tests, and noticed that when the app starts up, the user is already signed in and lands on the page after sign in. I don't know why this happens, maybe because the app has been running previously on the same device in development mode with a signed in user?

Is there a way to start the tests with no previous state, no sessions, etc? I can't find anything in the documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setUp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/setUp.html) and [tearDown](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/tearDown.html) to set/clear state before/after each test.

```
setUp(() async {
  // TODO
});

tearDown(() async {
  // TODO
});
```